# How do i put a Listview.builder in a column so i can put another widget on top of it?

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, firebase-storage

[image]

Below is the screen shot of the page which shows the listview of restaurants, i want to put a text widget and search bar on to p of it but when i put it in a column i get an error

Comment: post your code and error

Comment: Wrap ListView with Expanded .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```dart
YourSearchBar(),
Expanded(
  child: ListView()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the listview in a column and column in singlechildscrollview and set physics of listview as NeverScrollableScrollPhysics.

**Code:-**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             YourSearchBar(),
             Text('your text'),
             ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount:10,//replace 10 with the count of elements in list
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return  yourWidget();//return here the widget you want to show(your cake design one)
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
```